# Using CouchDB Pull replication from a read only server

Tags: couchdb, replication

I have a CouchDB server that is running behind a front end proxy which only allows `GET`, `HEAD` and `OPTIONS` requests. `POST`, `PUT` and `DELETE` are all disallowed.

When I set up replication on my local machine to pull from the remote server it works fine, until it reaches the end, when it tries to `POST` to `/_ensure_full_commit`. This returns a `401 Unauthorized` response and causes the replication to crash, and restarts at the beginning.

Can I prevent CouchDB replication from calling `/_ensure_full_commit` or do I need to change the front end proxy configuration to allow `POST`s to this url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the replicator code just always tries to commit to BOTH servers as part of the replication checkpoint process: https://github.com/apache/couchdb/blob/master/src/couch_replicator/src/couch_replicator.erl#L695

So for now the quickest solution would be to fake a "success" response at the proxy level or simply pass that request through, especially since neither of us know whether it's "necessary" or not.

But I'd also strongly encourage you to [ask on the mailinglist and/or file a bug](http://couchdb.apache.org/community/issues.html) about this though — it seems strange that you can't do a pull replication using only GET requests.

**Update**: Just remembered there's a pretty significant rewrite of the replicator code that recently landed on the develop branch, so another consideration is to try out the [new replicator in 1.2](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/COUCHDB-1024) first!

Comment: Thanks, I do read the mailing list but I must have missed the rewrite. I currently run https://launchpad.net/~kmpm/+archive/ppa/+build/2601645 which is a bit of an old 1.2 snapshot. I'll update it and then file a bug if it still doesn't work.